# Connected spaces and constant function

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $Y$ a discrete space. Prove that a space $X$ is connected if only if every $f:X\to Y$ is constant.

My incomplete attempt:

Ok, If $X$ isn't connected then there are $A, B $ open sets such that $X = A \cup B$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. So we have $  f(X)=f(A \cup B) 
= f(A) \cup f(B)$, my objective is to show that $f(A) \neq f(B)$ for some $f$ then $f$ isn't constant, But how?

And the otherwise I don't know

Comment: Your attempt to prove the "only if" direction is off to a good start. Note that you're trying to prove the *negation* of the "every $f$" statement, which is a "there exists $f$" statement. So can you use your $A$ and $B$ to construct a nonconstant $f$? As for the "if" direction, you can proceed similarly—start with a nonconstant $f$ and use it to construct $A$ and $B$....

Comment: I think for the statement to hold you need $Y$ to contain at least 2 points...

Answer (score 1):

Ferra's comment is spot-on. Let $Y = \{0\}$. Then for **any** space $X$ (such as $X = \{1, 2\}$), there's **exactly one** function from $X$ to $Y$, namely the one defined by: 
$$
f : Y \to X : y \mapsto 0.
$$

Your claim would then show that *every* space is connected (including my example $X$), which is not true. Hence the claim must be false.

Comment: OK, but if Y has 2 points? how I can solve it?

Comment: Well, first you ask a question that has an actual answer (i.e., you edit your question -- or better still, ask a new one, so that this answer doesn't look stupid). The new question includes the hypothesis that $Y$ has at least two points.